# AS3 - Multiple Images Turn On/Off Not Working with Second MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok this has been driving me insane. My AS3 knowledge isn't the best in the world, but I'm trying to work out where I'm going wrong with all of this.

Basically, What I'm trying to do is at certain times, make visible/invisble two different MovieClips.

The weird thing is, one is responding. And the other isn't. They are both identical aside from jpeg contents and names. Is there a setting I'm missing? Both have matched MovieClip names and Instance names... but when I use the code below, HOP1 turns off/on, but HOP2 refuses to! Am i just missing some stupidly obvious preference?

I will mention, I'll have to modify the code to work with two different MovieClips, but right now I just want both files to turn off!

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import com.boo.CustomDate;
    import com.boo.ScreensaverSimple;

    public class Generic extends MovieClip {

        // This is where you can set the Hour of Power time start and end time (in 24 hour format e.g. 1330 for 1:30pm)
        // If there is no hour of power, simply set both numbers to 0
        private var HourOfPowerStartTime:Number = 0;
        private var HourOfPowerEndTime:Number = 0;

        private var ss:ScreensaverSimple;

        public var time_check_timer:Timer;

        private var delay_add_timer:Timer;

        public function Generic() {
            Mouse.hide();

            ss = new ScreensaverSimple;
            ss.setScreensaver(screens);

            HOP2.visible = false;

            time_check_timer = new Timer(1000);
            time_check_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkTime);

            delay_add_timer = new Timer(1,1);
            delay_add_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addAllChildren);
            delay_add_timer.start();    
        }

        public function addAllChildren(evt:TimerEvent=null):void {
            delay_add_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addAllChildren);
            delay_add_timer.stop();
            delay_add_timer = null;

            time_check_timer.start();

            checkTime();
        }

        public function checkTime(evt:TimerEvent=null):void {
            checkHOP2();
        }

        private function checkHOP1():void {
            if(HourOfPowerStartTime == 0 && HourOfPowerEndTime == 0)
            {
                if(HOP2.visible == true)
                {
                    HOP2.visible = false;
                }

                return;
            }

            var CurrentTime:Number = CustomDate.return24HourNumber();

            if(CurrentTime >= HourOfPowerStartTime && CurrentTime <= HourOfPowerEndTime)
            {
                if(HOP2.visible == false)
                {
                    HOP2.visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(HOP2.visible == true)
                {
                    HOP2.visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: HOP2 is not declared for starters. Trace HOP2 for it could be inaccessible. Then, you might have 2 identical copies of HOP2 one over another. Trace all children with their names of the display container in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(HOP2.visible == true)
{
    HOP2.visible = false;
}
```

Fist thing the `if` condition is complete redundant here. If you think about it, those lines work exactly the same as this one alone:

```
HOP2.visible = false;
```

Also `(HOP2.visible == true)` would be exactly the same as `(HOP2.visible)` and also you can assign value of condition check directly to variable. Generally you can reduce your function to:

```
private function checkHOP1():void {
  HOP2.visible = (HourOfPowerStartTime || HourOfPowerEndTime);
  if (!HOP2.visible) return;
  var CurrentTime:Number = CustomDate.return24HourNumber();
  HOP2.visible = (CurrentTime >= HourOfPowerStartTime && CurrentTime <= HourOfPowerEndTime);
}
```

Then I see you call to `checkHOP2()` :

```
public function checkTime(evt:TimerEvent=null):void {
    checkHOP2();
}
```

but I don't see the `checkHOP2()` function defined in code you gave.

Similarly I don't see form where you call your `checkHOP1()` function you have posted. And also I don't get why change `HOP2` instance inside function named `checkHOP1()` . Is it suppose to be some kind of obfuscation?

Comment: That did it! The combination of the code cleanup and double checking all call names did the trick. I think there were conflicts when trying to double up the code but that's done the trick! Thank you so much!